# need an ip location lookup

Tags: ip-geolocation

anyone know of a decent site where i can lookup where an ip address is?

e.g. if i have ip address x.x.x.x.x and i want to know if that ip is in london or scotland.

i've been going around google and what the sites i have found are saying is that ip x is located in location london when it shud be roughly 250 miles away from there.
thanks 
p.s. must be free

Comment: exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884099/ip-location-database (etc.)

Comment: not an exact duplicate. he is asking how its done.

i'm asking where to find a decent one.

major difference :)

Comment: by the way max mind does the same thing.

Comment: The free providers will generally only provide coarse location data, e.g. the city that your ISP's netblock is registered in.  You will most likely need to pay to get more accurate information.  Even then it's not guaranteed that you can locate any single IP to within a particular town.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maxmind is an IP location database that will allow you to lookup IP address locations. Maxmind technology is behind quite a lot of IP tracing software and websites, including Visual IP Trace.

Dan

http://www.visualiptrace.com

Answer (score 1):

you can use [http://whois.domaintools.com/](http://whois.domaintools.com) for example http://whois.domaintools.com/stackoverflow.com and for ip information for example http://whois.domaintools.com/69.59.196.211

Answer (score 1):

[hostip.info](http://hostip.info) is a free (community-based) solution that works well and has reasonable accuracy. It also has an [API](http://www.hostip.info/use.html) for easy integration, or you can [download their complete database](http://www.hostip.info/dl/index.html) if you need quick or heavy access.

Answer (score 0):

I use this one all the time.  It allows 20 lookups per day.  http://www.ip2location.com/

As far as I can tell, it usually gets it right, though there are uncertainties for many IP addresses due to the way ISPs manage them.

Comment: thats the first one i tried. thank